# generar codigo "PE-0000001" usando el incremento MYSQL, con trigger

Tags: php, mysql, trigger, autoincremento

estoy queriendo hacer un autoincremento de código usando el AUTOINCREMENTO DE LA BASE DE DATOS y a este agregarle un TRIGGER para que pueda generar el código, ejemplo: "PE-0000001"

**mi tabla:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ruoli` (
  `idRol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nomrol` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `detrol` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date_add` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `statrol` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

como puedo hacer para que mi **idRol**, pueda usarse como autoincremento, y que el trigger agregue "PE-000000" y agregue al autoincremento.

gracias

Answer (score 0):

hasta donde yo se, no puedes usar AutoIncrement en un campo que no sea de tipo NUMBER. Lo que podrías hacer, si de verdad quieres tener un campo con el formato que mencionas `PE-0001` podrias almacenarlo en otra columna y automatizarlo con un trigger similar a este:

```
delimiter //
create trigger actualizarNombre BEFORE insert on nombreTabla for each row 
BEGIN

WHILE LENGTH(new.id) < 8 DO
    SET new.id = CONCAT("0",new.id);
END WHILE;
SET new.id = CONCAT("P",new.id); -- RESULT: P00000001

END;//
```

Otra solución, seria crearte algún algoritmo similar antes de realizar la instrucción a la base de datos.

Un saludo.

Comment: una consulta, es posible mostar el nuevo codigo de registro en el input(html,php) ?

Comment: La solución ahí seria crearte una función en MYSQL que cuando la llames te devuelva el nuevo input. Dentro de dicha función puedes portar una lógica similar a la antes comentada para que devuelva el nuevo ID.