# GENERAR CODIGO ALFANUMERICO CON AUTO INCREMENTO PHP "RU-0000001" usando autoincrement

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, autoincremento

quisiera una ayuda, estoy queriendo que se me genere un codigo autoincrementado segundario "TR-0000001", tengo en mi tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `ruoli` (
`idRuoli` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, // este es la llave primaria
`codrol` varchar(255) NOT NULL, //el codigo que se generarà en php
`nomrol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`detrol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`dateadd_rol` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`statrol` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
)
```

ahora en php tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
$query_id = mysqli_query($connectionString, "SELECT RIGHT(codrol,7) as codrol FROM ruoli ORDER BY codrol DESC LIMIT 1") or die('Error : '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
if (mysqli_num_rows($query_id) <> 0) {
    $data_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_id);
    $cod_ruolo  = intval($data_id['codrol']) + 1; // usar intval() aquí
} else {
    $cod_ruolo = 1;
}
$codidruolo = str_pad($cod_ruolo, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$cod_ruolo  = "RU-$codidruolo";
?>
```

en el campo del imput esta denominado el id,name = "cod_ruolo"

y el tipo de conexion que uso es "$connectionString"

no puedo darle solucion hasta la fecha, agradezco su apoyo.
buen dia

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] y **añadir** lo que intentes y lo que tampoco funcionó en esos intentos. Abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta :)

Comment: ¿Es la [misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577017/generar-codigo-pe-0000001-usando-el-incremento-mysql-con-trigger)?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [generar codigo "PE-0000001" usando el incremento MYSQL, con trigger](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577017/generar-codigo-pe-0000001-usando-el-incremento-mysql-con-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente el problema esté en que la columna `codigo` que devuelve la sentencia es tratada por tu código PHP como un string y no como un entero. Hice una prueba convirtiendo el valor a entero con `intval()` y ya parece funcionar correctamente:

```
<?php

$query_id = mysqli_query($connectionString, "SELECT RIGHT(codrol,7) as codigo FROM ruoli ORDER BY codrol DESC LIMIT 1") or die('Error : '.mysqli_error($mysqli));;

if (mysqli_num_rows($query_id) <> 0) {
    $data_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_id);
    $codigo  = intval($data_id['codigo']) + 1; // usar intval() aquí
} else {
    $codigo = 1;
}

$codidruolo = str_pad($codigo, 7, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$cod_ruolo  = "RU-$codidruolo";

?>
```

Comment: hola, 

corregi lo siguiente, pero aun asi no me carga nada y por consola no me sale ningun error:

ando con este problema hace un par de dias :C

Comment: El código que has colgado posteriormente no incluye en ningún sitio `intval()`...

Comment: hola,  denuevo.
 acabo de corregir el codigo, subi denuevamente el codigo, pero aun tengo y me genera el mismo problema.

Comment: **hola, corregi la lineas de codigo en la publicacion de la pregunta.**